# MOSS 2007 filtering a list ONLY if filter specified

Tags: sharepoint, filter, moss

Hi I have a sharepoint list that I want to filter based on text in the title, I want to beable to do a "Title contains" filter rather than an exact match, so I have gone to SPD and added a text box and go button to a page that contains the list. I have connected the 2 via a parameter and filtered based on that in the web part. This all works great

BUT..... When the page is initially shown the list is blank because the filter is blank and that doesn't match any Tiotkes in the list.....

What I'd really like to be able to do is show the entire list if the parameter is blank and opnly apply the filter if there is some text in it but I cant for the life of me figure out how to achieve it.

Any help would be really appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: I'm Not sure how you have connected both did you use xslt based web parts ?

Comment: The short answer is yes I think - What I did was add a web part page with a list added from the Main Sharepoint UI which I think adds a listViewWebPart. I then right clicked it in SPD to convert it to an XSL Data view which I think converts it to a DataFormWebPart.

Comment: They are connected via a parameter that gets its value from the control and used in a "contains" filter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In This case you would have to tweak your xsltto handle a default condition  and create a default value for the parameter. If you want complete solution please paste your data view webpart xslt here